# How to list all the project variables in a gitlab project via GitLab V4 api

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'd like to list all the project variables in a gitlab project. I have followed their official [documentation](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/variables.html#id2) but seems like I couldn't get it to work.

Below is my code:

```
import gitlab, os

# authenticate
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com/', private_token=os.environ['GITLAB_TOKEN'])

group = gl.groups.get(20, lazy=True)
projects = group.projects.list(include_subgroups=True, all=True)
for project in projects:
    project.variables.list()
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'GroupProject' object has no attribute 'variables'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `group.list` uses the [groups list project API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-a-groups-projects) and returns `GroupProject` objects, not `Project` objects. `GroupProject` objects do not have a `.variables` manager, but `Project` objects *do*.

To resolve this, you must extract the ID from the `GroupProject` object and call the projects API separately to get the `Project` object:

```py
group = gl.groups.get(20, lazy=True)
group_projects = group.projects.list(include_subgroups=True, all=True)
for group_project in group_projects:
    project = gl.projects.get(group_project.id)  # can be lazy if you want
    project.variables.list()
```

Comment: Thanks!! That worked. I'm specifically looking to list protected variables only, instead of all the vars. Do you if there is a special param for that? I have tried `project.variables.list(protected=True)` but that didn't work.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no filtering for that in the [list API itself](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html) (therefore no such keyword parameter in the Python API wrapper) but it is relatively simple to do that filtering in python: `protected_variables = [var for var in project.variables.list(all=True) if var.protected is True]` @blackPanther

Comment: Great, it did the trick, thanks! now `protected_variables` is a list of classes like `[<ProjectVariable key:API_TOKEN>, <ProjectVariable key:WEBHOOK_URL>]`, whereas I'm just looking for `[API_TOKEN, WEBHOOK_URL]`

Comment: @blackPanther those are _instances_, not classes. You can extract the information you want from the object. For example `var.value` -- if I've answered your original question, please consider voting and accepting it. If you still need more help beyond that, consider raising a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [FAQ](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html):

> #### I get an `AttributeError` when accessing attributes of an object retrieved via a `list()` call.
>
> Fetching a list of objects, doesn’t always include all attributes in the objects. To retrieve an object with all attributes use a `get()` call.

Adapting the example to your code:

```py
for project in projects:
    project = gl.projects.get(project.id)
    project.variables.list()
```